# How to combine sub queries, order by and grouping of max records?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following table for recording metrics of sports players per match:

```
class MatchResult(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'match_result'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    p1_id= Column(Integer, index=True)
    p1_metric = Column(Float)
    p2_id= Column(Integer, index=True)
    p2_metric = Column(Float)
```

I want to get the maximum metric for every unique player id (whether they were p1 or p2) and ordered by metric.

This is as far as I have got:

```
p1 = session.query(
    MatchResult.p1_id.label("player_id"),
    MatchResult.p1_metric.label("metric")
).subquery()
p2 = session.query(
    MatchResult.p2_id.label("player_id"),
    MatchResult.p2_metric.label("metric")
).subquery()
union = p1.union(p2)
upset = session.query(
    union.c.player_id,
    func.max(union.c.metric).label("max_metric")
)
upset = upset.group_by(union.c.player_id)
upset = upset.order_by(union.c.max_metric)
```

But I'm hitting an issue that I can't union two sub queries so I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Alias' object has no attribute 'union'
```

How would I solve this issue?